# Scale background image so that it always keeps its aspect ratio and stays centered

Tags: html, css, background, resize, scaling

I'd like to set a webpage background image to scale with the browser window so that it never loses its original aspect ratio (becomes stretched), and so that the image itself stays basically centered. After the window reaches a small enough size, I want the image to overflow (disappear) on both the left and right sides, not just the right side, as it does by default if the image is absolutely positioned.

Here is an example of what I'm doing right now: http://jsfiddle.net/S59EW/2/

```
#background img {
  position: absolute;
  min-height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

(The image has to be within a div positioned absolutely because of some javascript I'm using that applies to it.)

If you resize the jsfiddle window you'll see that the image keeps its aspect ratio only if you don't make the window too tall. Then the image is stretched vertically.

And if you remove "height: auto" you get the same thing except the image stops resizing after a certain point and disappears on the right/bottom sides but not on the top/left sides.

```
#background img {
  position: absolute;
  min-height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

So, I need:

The background image to always occupy the entire window without scrollbars.
The image to always keep aspect ratio.
The image to overflow onto the left and right side after a certain browser size threshold, so that it remains basically centered.

Thanks everyone

Comment: How is this? http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/S59EW/9/show/

Answer (score 5):

You can set the div background through the CSS, that way the image will fill the div and the sides will cutoff when the div is resized smaller. This code will center the image within the div and cutoff at the edges when shrunken down:

HTML:

```
<div id="background"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#background {
    position: absolute;
    min-height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-ayEwJpMGTPQ/USqliwPWo1I/AAAAAAAAHtI/ab6NHVy0Q48/s1600/tree.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover; /* Add in these */
    -moz-background-size: cover;    /* four lines to */
    -o-background-size: cover;      /* remove the white space*/
    background-size: cover;         /* around images */
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S59EW/11/)

and [full screen JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S59EW/11/embedded/result/)

[Updated JSFiddle with background-size property included to remove white space](http://jsfiddle.net/S59EW/53/)

[Updated full screen version](http://jsfiddle.net/S59EW/53/embedded/result/)

[Updated with slideshow](http://jsfiddle.net/MxvQz/3/)

[Updated fullscreen with slideshow](http://jsfiddle.net/MxvQz/3/embedded/result/)

You may need to play with the aspect ratio of the background photos in order to get the look you want.

Comment: This is close to what I want. But when you stretch the browser window to a greater horizontal resolution that the image itself, white space appears on the left and right sides. Also, I have several background images cycling, fading in and out, which is controlled by javascript. I don't believe I can still do that if I set the background url through css. Is there any way to get this effect without setting the div bg image through css?

Comment: You also can use `background-images` as a slide show. You would just cycle through the `classes` or `ids` that have each image in their own `class`/`id`.

Comment: To get rid of the white space, you can add background-size: cover; This property is not supported by default by all browsers, so you need to add some browser prefixes. You can use this property for any background image, regardless of its original size. Not sure what JavaScript your using for the slideshow, but this CSS property should work for a slideshow. If you want to post the JS, I can see how to make it work. I'll update my answer with an updated JSFiddle.

Comment: Hi Sean. Here's a fiddle indicating what I'm doing now (http://jsfiddle.net/MxvQz/1/) -- obviously the background techniques offered here have not been implemented, as I don't have the div bg image set through css

Comment: I added another JSFiddle link at the bottom of my answer with your code modified to work with the full screen background images. This should work for what you are trying to achieve. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have these two options, one is `CSS` only but it would need `media queries` at a small width.

Here is the background image [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/S59EW/21/show/), in this one it will scale exactly how you want it.

Finally, drum roll please, if you need the image to be a tag its self and act this way well there is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/S59EW/20/show/) for that. :p

First `CSS`,

```
#background img {
  position: absolute;
  min-height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: -40%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1700px) {
  #background img {
    margin-top: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: The image loses its aspect ratio in both of these examples. It functions basically the same way my initial code did.

Comment: Refer to my first link for 100% good to go `background-image`, I had the wrong link there. The next link on my large screen is doing what you want which is epic for an `img` tag. I am currently trying to make it work for smaller sizes but I'll let you know.

Comment: Yes, that first link is doing just what I need. Thanks so much, I appreciate that. Is there any chance you could produce a fiddle indicating how I could create a 'slide show' of multiple background images using the class/id method you refer to above, with no flash or white/black space between background images? I'm not clear about that technique

Comment: Josh, could you edit your first fiddle to show how to modify that solution to include one or two more images fading into one another every few seconds?

Comment: @user2985093 Here is a jsfiddle to show how to make this into a slideshow. The jQuery I provided is not for a slideshow but just to show the effect. http://jsfiddle.net/S59EW/65/

Comment: @user2985093 here is another fiddle with all images, http://jsfiddle.net/S59EW/68/show/.