# Centring a background keeping ratio to stretch to fit screen

Tags: html, css, background, wrapper

Probably abit of a beginners question but having difficulty with this. I am using a template from 'initialzr' in order to make a one page webpage. The header and footer are okay, but I wish to have a background image that I want centered stretched across the screen in this div so the screen will keep the right ratio. I've looked at several sites using absolute centring and a couple of answers from here ([Responsive Image full screen and centered - maintain aspect ratio, not exceed window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490334/responsive-image-full-screen-and-centered-maintain-aspect-ratio-not-exceed-wi)) and ([Scale background image so that it always keeps its aspect ratio and stays centered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944718/scale-background-image-so-that-it-always-keeps-its-aspect-ratio-and-stays-center)) and wondered if this was the way to take it?

So pretty much my code stands as...

HTML:

```
 <div class="main-container">
        <div id="background"> 
        <img src="img/bg.png" style="no-repeat; background-size: cover;"/>
          <div class="main wrapper clearfix">
  <div id="header">
<p>test</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 #background img {
position: absolute;
min-height:100%;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
top: 0;
left: 0;
margin:0px auto;
```

}

When I run this code, it covers the entire screen and doesn't show the header and footer that I've already included. Any help or examples is greatly appreciated. Apologises on the newbie question and if it has been answered before.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is covering your header and footer will be due to it being `position:absolute;`

You will need to either `z-index:-1;` on your img

Or add z-index on your header and footer. (Remember to apply z-index it must have positioning on the element. i.e. `position:relative`)

Comment: Thanks its starting to take shape but the footer is now halfway up the page over the image. Will this be due to the size of the image?

Comment: As your image is position:absolute; nothing else will be able to see it's size. What is your footer styling?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a div to use the background image. Put the background image as a CSS property on the `body`. Then use a `background-size: cover`. This will make it size as big as possible while covering the entire area and keeping its aspect ratio.

```
body {
    background-image: url('images/image.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```